# flip div is not working properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem regarding use of flip div with the help of css in Google Chrome.
Reference site is [here](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php).

It's working properly on Mozilla but it's problematic on some versions of Chrome.
Left side image is working properly but right side image is not working properly.

Image example is

[image]

You can also check the image to see the exact problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please fix your questions text by editing it.

Comment: I have no problems with the original pages pics in my chromium browser. Not sure what your screenshot is meant to show...

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, where you've got tags, e.g.

```
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}
```

Duplicate them and apply the follow infront of them

```
  -webkit-
```

So you'll end up with

```
 .flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}
```

WebKit is a rendering engine for Google Chrome and Safari. Other browsers have their own and it's probably good practise to support use all browser engines.

```
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s; // Firefox 16+, IE10+, Opera 12.5+
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;  // Chrome & Safari 3.5+
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -moz-transition: 0.6s;  // Firefox 3.5 - 15
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -ms-transition: 0.6s;  // IE9
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -o-transition: 0.6s;  // Opera 10.5-12
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All what you need is have a complete CSS vendor prefixes. here's a useful tool [prefixr](http://prefixr.com/index.php) you can work around with its completely free.